# Memory crash updating UIActivityIndicatorView

Tags: iphone

Whenever I am trying to update the `UIActivityIndicatorView` from a thread, the app is getting crashed by throwing an exception

> modifying layer that is being finalized - 0x7e177fd0
>   -[CALayer removeAnimationForKey:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7e177fd0

When I try tracking the memory leaks form the mallocDebugger tool, this crash is not happening at all the time happening 1 out of 10

please help me out from this memory issue

Thread implementation:

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];

[autoRechargeCell addSubview:activityIndicator];
[self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
if( [PennyTalkAPI getBalanceInfoForAccount:appDelegate.accountNumber withPIN:appDelegate.pinNumber])
{   
    [autoRechargeCell.switchField setOn:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"AutoRecharge"]];
    [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< 
}
else
{
    [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
}

[pool release];
```

This is the code I have written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are updating it from secondary thread that why it is crashing call this on main thread like

```
   [self.activityIndicator performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(stopAnimating) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

I think it may help you ....

Answer (score 1):

See this. 
 add  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self]; to UIActivityIndicatorView+AFNetworking.m dealloc 
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/2748

Comment: Thanks zartha i am finding the soultion from your answer. thanks again.